# In the Predator movies, did makers mention anything about female Predators?

Tags: character, predator, aliens-vs-predator, aliens-vs-predator-requiem

The Predator movie franchise, the Predator (1987), Predator 2 (1990), Predators (2010) and also upcoming movie The Predator (2018).

In the previous Predator movies, we can see Predators hunt human's & animals. In these movies, all the Predators are males.

My question is, in these Predator movies, did the makers mention anything about female Predators? Even if they exist, are they hunting like male Predators?

[image]

Comment: “in these Movies all the Predator are Male's” — are they? Says who?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In films there is no mention of Female Predators (Yautja), but in extended canon there are female predators:

From [wikia:](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja)

> ## Reproduction:
>
> The subject of Yautja reproduction is not touched upon in
>   the slightest within the films, there are many members of the species
>   seen but none blatantly female by human standards.
>
> - **Alien vs. Predator: Prey:** Female predators are apparently not hunters, but are still none-the-less equals in Yautja society and
>     mentality. "Lou-dte kalei" was a derogatory term that was sometimes
>     used to refer to females, it literally meant "child-maker." The
>     warrior Dachande had never heard the name spoken to a female's face.
> - **Aliens vs Predator: Deadliest of the Species:** A Female Predator (Called Big Mama) was seen in the comic and Shows only a little
>     distinction from males. She does not appear to have any sort of
>     noticeable mammary glands in the comic, but the covers show this
>     differently. She was extremely protective and caring of her progeny
>     and a powerful warrior.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens/Predator:_Deadliest_of_the_Species) link for *Aliens vs Predator: Deadliest of the Species*:

> Claremont remarked that the editor of the series gave him far more creative freedom than he was accustomed to: "So long as I don't violate the basic parameters of the Alien/Predator universe - there's a limit to what we can establish about them, and I'm stretching that by establishing a female Predator - I can do pretty much what I want. I can write the kind of characters I want, and that's a freedom I haven't had in a long time, especially as regarding the X-Men."

Comment: If somebody needed to watch the predator series, what would be the right order?

Comment: @Vishwa If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. :P

Comment: @Vishwa: The correct order is 1. Watch *Predator*; 2. Stop.

Comment: @AJ Thanks, I almost forget that we have Ask question button somewhere here.. gonna start lokin for it right now ;)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That was my previous experience, however from Ankit's answer I began to grow kinda curiosity about predators.. :)

Comment: @Vishwa [here is the button](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ;)

Comment: @AnkitSharma ooh.. you saved me a ton of time, now I have nothing to do. gonna do a something physically challenging.. okay, war it is.. what could be more daunting, modern or advanced warfare?  ;) :D

Comment: @Vishwa: the Alien vs. Predator comics, sure, go read those, they’re good. Well, the first one was. I applied my Predator movies system and stopped at the first.

Answer (score 1):

In the existing movies, there are no references to the female Predators, although they are speculated to be in the upcoming The Predator movie. However, there are a few notable Female Yautja (that are actually named characters) in the books and graphic novels:

- Big Mama - From the comic AvP: Deadliest of the Species. A big
  Predator with no female features (breasts) and no special
  armor/costume. She is actually quite badass and survives the hunt.
- Sister Midnight - from the Witchblade/Aliens/Darkness/Predator:
  Mindhunter crossover comic. Looks feminine, has breasts and has a
  dress like costume. Has a special relationship with Witchblade,
  fights some Aliens, detonates her self-destruct and dies.
- Vagouti - From the Predator: If It Bleeds novel story Rematch (the
  story is a sequel to the book Predator: Turnabout). There is not much
  physical description on her but she is hunting together with her
  mate. They are both killed by humans.

There is also Machiko Noguchi, who is a human female who joined the Predators (she is often mistaken for a female Predator). There is more information and pictures about them here: [Female Yautja](https://www.avpcentral.com/female-yautja)

Comment: This does not answer the question about whether female Predators are reference in the **movies**.